# What's the easiest language for a completely custom GUI? (Windows)

Tags: windows, user-interface

I want to make a simple program. Don't really care what it does, actually. I know that might sound a little silly to you guys - the majority of questions on SO are pretty srs.

The thing is, I'm fairly new to computer programming - I've made some very simple applications for a programming class (hello world, a calculator, you know - the ropes) and even though I understand the elegance of using a command line, I think making a little window with custom check boxes and text areas that I can train my right index finger on, I'll feel that it's truly MINE and worth building into something worthwhile as a next project, as opposed to a bland, faceless .NET\Office2007 looking program. I hope you understand. Programming should be fun, right? ;)

I have very limited experience with ruby (I started reading the pickaxe book) and C++, but it shouldn't be THAT hard to just overlay an image over a borderless window or something and re-skin some buttons, right?

What's the easiest language to use for this purpose?

What's the best way to get started?

Comment: How custom? Your own controls?

Comment: try [Qt (framework)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(framework)). It's fun :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF is an excellent choice for customising controls this way, or creating your own controls with relative ease.
Not only does it allow you to create controls in any shape you want, it also allows skinning existing controls in whatever shape you want.

A few short lines in a single 'resource dictionary' are enough to replace (for example) all buttons with your customised button template.

example :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid Margin="0">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" Name="border" CornerRadius="5,5,5,5" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" />
                        <ContentPresenter TextBlock.FontSize="16" TextBlock.FontFamily="Lucida Sans Unicode" 
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                          Name="content" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SelectionDefaultBackgroundBrush}" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="Gray" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DefaultBorderBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource DefaultBorderBrush}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource DefaultBackgroundBrush}" />
    </Style>
```

will make all buttons with rounded corners, and lucida sans for a font-face
WPF is available for most .NET languages, including VB.NET, and C#

Answer (score -1):

For quick GUI mock-ups you can't beat VB6 (I've not used VB.Net so maybe that's similar). You can get a free download of Visual Studio Express from Microsoft. However, if you're going for ownerdrawn controls then VB may not be a good choice, it's certainly possible but you're going to have to hook into message queues and get to grips with GDI.

Alternatively, QT Creator has a pretty good GUI generator.

Comment: Suppose you go with VB6, there are still plenty of UI frameworks to choose from.
Also, VB wasn't intended for mockups. that's what tools like Balsamiq are for.